# Writing an array that displays all 5 int

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked by my professor about writing an array that displays all 5 int. He gave us the numbers and this is what I tried doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setS(1);
    setW(-3);
    setA(78);
    setG(23);
    setY(-1005);

}

public static int getS() {
    System.out.print('s');
    return s;
}

public static void setS(int s) {
    chapter7.s = s;
}

public static int getW() {
    System.out.print('w');
    return w;
}

public static void setW(int w) {
    chapter7.w = w;
}

public static int getA() {
    System.out.print(a);
    return a;
}

public static void setA(int a) {
    chapter7.a = a;
}

public static int getG() {
    System.out.print(g);
    return g;
}

public static void setG(int g) {
    chapter7.g = g;
}

public static int getY() {
    System.out.print(y);
    return y;
}

public static void setY(int y) {
    chapter7.y = y;
}

}
```

I set all the characters as values to the number soi wouldn't have to and while i was doing that I created separate methods so it would process separately.
But it doesn't seem to display through the console. What did I do wrong?

Comment: As in creating an array that has all values as `5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Array of size 5 with all the values

```
public static void printArray(int[] arr){
System.out.println("Array : ");
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
System.out.println(arr[i]);
}

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] arr = {1, -3, 78, 13, -1005};
printArray(arr);
}
```

Comment: Does the variable name have to arr?

Comment: It's not compulsory. You can change variable name according to your choice

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class ArrayStuff{

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

 for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){//all relevant ints stored here
 myList.add(stdin.nextInt());
   }

}
}
```

To get the contents of this array, you want to use the myList.get(index) method

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class ArrayTest {
   private static int s;
   private static int w;
   private static int a;
   private static int g;
   private static int y;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setS(1);
    setW(-3);
    setA(78);
    setG(23);
    setY(-1005);
    getS();
    getW();
    getA();
    getG();
    getY();

}

/**
 * @return the s
 */
public static int getS() {
    System.out.println("getS():" + s);
    return s;
}

/**
 * @param s
 *            the s to set
 */
public static void setS(int s) {
    ArrayTest.s = s;
}

/**
 * @return the w
 */
public static int getW() {
    System.out.println("getW():" + w);
    return w;
}

/**
 * @param w
 *            the w to set
 */
public static void setW(int w) {
    ArrayTest.w = w;
}

/**
 * @return the a
 */
public static int getA() {
    System.out.println("getA():" + a);
    return a;
}

/**
 * @param a
 *            the a to set
 */
public static void setA(int a) {
    ArrayTest.a = a;
}

/**
 * @return the g
 */
public static int getG() {
    System.out.println("getG():" + g);
    return g;
}

/**
 * @param g
 *            the g to set
 */
public static void setG(int g) {
    ArrayTest.g = g;
}

/**
 * @return the y
 */
public static int getY() {
    System.out.println("getY():" + y);
    return y;
}

/**
 * @param y
 *            the y to set
 */
public static void setY(int y) {
    ArrayTest.y = y;
   }
  }
}
```